# Given that $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n$ converge, does $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n f(\sin n)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assume that $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n$ is a non-negative, convergent series. Let $f$ be a continuous function with domain $\mathbb{R}$. I have to figure out if the series

$\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n f(\sin n)$

1. converge
2. diverge
3. not enough information to decide

The only possible test that is applicable here is I think basic comparison test, somehow using the fact that sin is bounded, but I have no idea how to proceed. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What is a  non-decreasing convergent series?

Comment: Converge, because $f(\sin(n))$ is bounded, that is $\sum_n^\infty a_n f(\sin(n)) \le M\sum_n^\infty a_n < \infty$ for some $M$, am I right?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy non-negative means for all n, $a_n \geq 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, sorry, my mistake. What I mean was non-negative, not non-decreasing.

Comment: @Hugo I think that makes sense, but how do I rigorously show that it is bounded? Do you think just stating the existence of $M$ is enough?

Comment: @abrakadabra_01: Note that $-1\le\sin n\le 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Therefore you just need to look at $f\big{|}_{[-1, 1]}$ and by continuity (and compactness of the restricted domain) there must be some $M\ge 0$ such that $|f\big{|}_{[-1, 1]}|\le M.$

Comment: @ abrakadabra_01 I think $f(x)$ is continuous function and $\sin(n) \in [-1,1]$ which is a closed interval . Then by the property of continuous function on closed interval. we can conclude that $f(\sin(n)) $ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$\{f(\sin n)|n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq f([-1,1])$$

now you can apply one of many useful properties of continuous functions on closed sets.